# Slow Query - uses views

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-view

Backend on the cloud using SQL Server Express 2008 R2
Frontend on Access 2013

I had a query that I recently had to add a subquery to to restrict the results.  The query took about 1 second to run before, but now takes about 70+.  I think the problem may be that I am using views in the query that are not indexed.  I'm pretty new to this and don't use Access/SQL much, so apologies if i am missing something obvious here.

This is my query code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vuSearch.PAID
    ,vuSearch.PDID
    ,ConcatAddress(Nz([Building_Name]), Nz([Building_No]), Nz([Street]), Nz([IndEst]), Nz([District]), Nz([Town]), Nz([Postcode])) AS Address
    ,vuSearch.Deal_Date
    ,vuSearch.Lease_End
    ,vuSearch.Break_Date
    ,vuSearch.Review_Date
    ,vuSearch.PropertyType
    ,vuSearch.Acting_For
    ,vuSearch.Landlord_Seller
    ,vuSearch.Tenant_Purchaser
    ,IIf(IsNull([vuSearch.GIA]), [vuSearch.NIA], [vuSearch.GIA]) AS MainArea
    ,vuDesc.Comments_Incentives
    ,tldDealSearch.Include
    ,vuSearch.Incomplete
FROM (
    vuSearch RIGHT JOIN tldDealSearch ON vuSearch.PDID = tldDealSearch.PDID
    )
LEFT JOIN vuDesc ON tldDealSearch.PDID = vuDesc.PDID
WHERE (
        (
            (vuSearch.PDID) IN (
                (
                    SELECT Max(v2.PDID)
                    FROM vuSearch AS v2
                    GROUP BY v2.PAID
                    )
                )
            )
        AND ((vuSearch.Incomplete) = False)
        );
```

I added indexes to the tldDealSearch table for the PDID and Include fields (I think I've done that right).  When I looked at the views on the backend however I could not add indexes as the views are no schema bound.

Is there anything I can do or should be looking at to speed this up?  I'm quite worried as right now there are only 300 records on the database - 70+ seconds?

I have checked everything on the 'Analyze performance' tool but not sure what to do next.

EDIT:
Thanks for the fast responses guys.

NZ - This is the Access NullToZero function i believe, or what replaced it.
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php

ConcatAddress - This is a function I use to put all elements of an address together in a readable format for inclusion in a report.

```
Public Function ConcatAddress(strBuildingName As String, strBuildingNo As String, strStreet As String, _
strIndEstate As String, strDistrict As String, strTown As String, strPostcode As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrRoutine
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(strBuildingName) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strBuildingName
    End If
    If Len(strBuildingNo) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strBuildingNo
        Else
            strSQL = strBuildingNo
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strStreet) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strStreet & ","
        Else
            strSQL = strStreet
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strIndEstate) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strIndEstate & ","
        Else
            strSQL = strIndEstate
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strDistrict) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strDistrict & ","
        Else
            strSQL = strDistrict
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strTown) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strTown
        Else
            strSQL = strTown
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strPostcode) > 0 Then
        If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " " & strPostcode
        Else
            strSQL = strPostcode
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
        ConcatAddress = strSQL
    Else
        ConcatAddress = ""
    End If
ErrExit:
    Exit Function
ErrRoutine:
    ConcatAddress = Empty
    Select Case Err
        Case 94
            'MsgBox "Postcode not found."
            Resume ErrExit
        Case Else
            MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
            Resume ErrExit
    End Select
End Function
```

## '#'#'#'#'#'#'

EDIT

I was asked to post the execution plan for the query, but that is not available in access.  I got a hack working that I think is close to what an execution plan is (couldn't get it to work with Access 2013 though).

[For Info]
Add a key and string to the registry - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines
Add key 'Debug' and add string 'JETSHOWPLAN' - Set the value to ON to record
(results should be in my documents or in location of database)

```
- Inputs to Query -
ODBC table 'vuSearch'
ODBC table 'vuSearch'
Table 'tldDealSearch'
ODBC table 'vuDesc'
- End inputs to Query -

01) Sort table 'vuDesc'
02) Outer Join table 'tldDealSearch' to result of '01)'
      using temporary index
      join expression "tldDealSearch.PDID=vuDesc.PDID"
1614631268) Remote SQL
03) Sort result of '02)'
04) Inner Join result of '02)' to result of '03)'
      using temporary index
      join expression "tldDealSearch.PDID=vuSearch.PDID"
      store result in temporary table
```

Seems to be alot of sorting going on so that must slow it down some.  Hope this is what you were looking for.

**EDIT**
The Access JETSHOWPLAN does not give much detail so I transferred the tldSearchData table to the backend and ran the query there.  I removed the concatAdderss (as it uses Access function) and also the IIF formula to determine which area to use.  The resultant execution plans are below.

Actual: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5o8fYhuyQ0ZODZCWHNIaS1KZ1k/view?usp=sharing
Estimated: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5o8fYhuyQ0ZU0lnRUhvaXVkc1k/view?usp=sharing
The query took 19 seconds to run directly from SQL (from the cloud server)

Comment: Mixing LEFT and RIGHT join... Very confusing to many people. (Most of us prefer LEFT JOINs.)

Comment: Show us function `ConcatAddress`

Comment: Maybe the compiler is trying to work out why you are obsessed with parentheses. What is NZ? It looks like a function and I'm guessing will be the cause of the issue. Also what is ConcatAddress?

Comment: look into: 1# replace `where ... in` with `inner join`, 2# ConcatAddress, 3#. Nz

Comment: Is this Access, Sql Server or VB? Is ConcatAddress a CLR?

Comment: This is a query in Access (2013)
The data on the back end is held on Sql Server.

Comment: ConcatAddress is a VBA Function - not heard of a CLR.

Comment: Have you tried running the query without the ConcatAddress line and seeing how long it takes?

Comment: Tried running after removing the concatAddress line.  72 seconds.

Comment: If your performance problems started when adding the subquery, the subquery is likely the problem.  Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: Had a quick look, but not sure where this is found in Access - can you direct me?

Comment: After more than a quick look, it appears that this is not a feature in Access.  Digging around I found a hack that allows you to edit the registry but unfortunately this did not work for me using Access 2013 and Win 8 (64 bit).  My home computer is win 7 and has Access 2002 (Office XP) - the hack works.  Details above with results.

Comment: Finally got the execution plans up.

Comment: I have added some non-clustered indexes to the tables behind the views which seems to help a little.  Not sure if i've done it correctly, but here's hoping.  Should I be looking at amending the code that makes the views themselves rather than relying on the default when the view was created?  Just found the SQL Sentry software - makes things easier to see, but still not sure about how to fix.  Will keep hunting.  TIA

Comment: Simply build the query on SQL server as a view, and then link to that view from Access. It will be SQL server that does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

place your sql on the server as a view/proc, then call that instead of trying to troubleshoot performance in Access.  Consider using a "passthrough" query, that will perform much, much faster compared to linked tables.